# Interpreting Fixed and Random Effects in Mixed-Effect Logit

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, stata, random-effects-model

I'm working with a large household-level dataset right now with households sampled from almost 30 countries. I'm running a mixed-effect logit (melogit command in Stata) with country as a blocking factor. I have one IV of principal interest (let's call it x1), several control variables, and other IVs of secondary interest. Further, I've theorized the effect of x1 on the binary outcome y varies across countries, and have included it as a random effect. The basic Stata code reads as: melogit y x1 x2 x3...xn ||country: x1, or.

I'm running into challenges interpreting the fixed effect odds ratio (OR) for the 'full' model, and the random intercept and slope of x1 for each country, extracted from the model.

The OR for the entire model for x1 is, let's say, 2.0. As theorized, the effect of x1 varies quite considerably. But, in numerous countries the OR of x1 is under < 1, whereas its effect in the other countries is either on par with the fixed effect OR (2.0), or higher (> 2.0). If my intent is to make some kind of generalizable claim of the effect of x1 on y, how can I interpret the random effects that run 'counter' to the reported fixed effect? I'd like to respect the complexity of these random effect results across countries, while still attending to the possibility of making broader claims of the data. What are some ways I could proceed forward in interpreting the diversity of random effects at the country level and the fixed effect of the full model in ways that go beyond 'recognizing variation exists across countries'?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about how you are estimating/predicting the country-specific slopes? I assume you are using `predict` in Stata, but what are you asking for?